# Linking Fast report file

Tags: c#, fastreport

I have designed a form on Fast report with my sql data.

Now I want to link this file to my C# project - how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this file as embedded resource and load it at run-time with [Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream.aspx).